# How to Integrate jar/war containing JAX-RS resource with the Quarkus

Tags: java, gradle, jax-rs, quarkus

I'm new to quarkus and what I'm trying to do is I've two JAX-RS application codebase .
I want to package code of both the app as single distribution package.

I want to package it as quarkus app.

To be more clear below is an example for the same .

---

App1 :(Can be Quarkus app or just JAX-RS war )
Contains Resources->  /rest/greetings

App2 :(Can be Quarkus app or just JAX-RS war )
Contains Resources->  /rest/hello

App3 :(Quarkus app which will be distributed)
Contains Resources-> /rest/greetings
/rest/hello

Uses App1 and App2 as jar or war dependancy

---

Basically I want to maintain separate codebase for two apps(you can say modules) and third app which is for packaging and distribution.

Idea behind this is to build app with configurable module like  in future if I have 5 modules and I just want to build and deliver app with 3 module I can do it .

I'm using gradle as build tool.

Comment: I think you got it right. What I like to do (albeit in Maven) is to have the "interesting" parts of my app in their own jars. E.g. one Jar with JAX-RS *interfaces* and DTOs, another one with implementations. Then, I depend on these these from another module that may be traditional `war` (for deployment to traditional app server) or a Quarkus app. The `war` or Quarkus module "assembles" the application with minimal effort. This way, I can create deployments for different types of servers. I hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: Yes somewhat like this but the problem is I want to keep one module specific endpoints and implementation  in one jar and another module specific endpoints and implementation in another jar so test-cases specific to module remains in that project.
I don't understand how can I achieve this with quarkus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that worked for me,
Added org.jboss.jandex plugin to my App1 and App2 so it generated jandex index and added both the app as dependency to my App3 so quarkus was able to load these annotated classes on start-up.
Doc for more info [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference)